# CollectionView showing EmptyView contents even after having a data in my list. Xamarin

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.forms, observable, collectionview

On Android, everything works just fine. You define your EmptyView and you see that when your list is empty. Unfortunately on iOS, this doesn’t work correctly. There is a bug in Xamarin.Forms that hasn’t been fixed yet, so it can happen that you see the EmptyView even if your list is not empty. I discovered this problem while working on my new app  (Android, iOS). Even if my list was not empty, on iOS the CollectionView was showing both the contents from ItemTemplate and EmptyView.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is that... My EmptyView content are not getting hide when there is data Collection.  EmptyView content should only show when Itemsource count of my collection view is zero or null in my case even after having a data in my collection view item source empty content are also visible

Comment: That's not a question.  Are you asking for a workaround?  Or for us to confirm that it is a bug?  You haven't provided any code or a [mcve].

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/15122

Comment: The issue mentioned in this blog i am facing the same ...and solution is provided in this blog but is there any other workaround to slove is this ?
 https://www.xamarinexpert.it/collectionview-on-xamarin-forms-how-to-solve-this-annoying-bug-on-ios/

Comment: What is wrong with the workaround you already have?  Why didn't you include this very useful information in your original question?

Comment: Ok, Sry my bad. Thanks for your all the support.